# Need to add an element to bootstrap multiselect from rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I need to add an element to bootstrap multiselect js in rails to a list of items that I have.

but I want it just below the select all column. Here is what I have done

```
$('#fs_reviewed_').multiselect({
    enableFiltering:true,
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    nonSelectedText: 'Reviewed By',
    selectAllText: 'Anyone'
});
<%= select_tag "fs_reviewed[]", options_for_select(@users.collect{|u| [u.full_name,u.id]}.push(['None'])),{:class=>'multiselect-all',:multiple=>'multiple'}%>
```

The none gets added to the last of the users list. How do I add to the 2nd place just below select all

Answer (score 0):

What if you add "None" as the first element of the array you pass to options_for_select?

```
<%= select_tag "fs_reviewed[]", options_for_select([["None"]] + @users.collect{|u| [u.full_name,u.id]}),{:class=>'multiselect-all',:multiple=>'multiple'}%>
```